# RAILS Ajax request domain name in url is being replaced by host domain name in Heroku production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have 2 Rails apps hosted in 2 seperate heroku servers. One for the front end app and another for the backend api app.

So in the front end app I have a .js file with an ajax request that looks like this.

```
function checkAvailability(){
        $.ajax({url: "https://peaceful-hollows-97855.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cleaning_services/" + $('#f_zipcode').val(), 
                success: function(result){
                if(result.status == 'success'){
                console.log(result);
                alert(result.message);
                }else{
                console.log(result);
                alert(result.message);  
            }   
          }
       });
    }
```

Now that's the domain name for my server side api app. I've hard coded it for now. But in production when I fire the request, the domain name is being changed for some reason. This is what I see in my console.

```
Request URL:https://desolate-river-10575.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cleaning_services/560017
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

What's happening here? How is it possibly replacing my hardcoded domain name with its own base url?

Comment: Turns out the link that I had saved in the environment variable in rails controller wasn't being loaded first and since the scripts are running first, the variable for the link is empty and it is getting replaced.